# Getting rid of HttpContext dependency - can I use thread storage instead

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing WEB API service that uses a lot of legacy components. The legacy components rely heavily on calls to `ContextInfo.ContextID` (this is referenced like zillion of times).

```
public static class ContextInfo
{
  public static int ContextID 
  {
    get { return (int)HttpContext.Current.Items["ContextID"]; }
  }
}

// sample legacy class
public class Legacy
{
   public void Foo()
   {
     if (ContextInfo.ContextID == 7)
     {
       Bar();
     }
   }
}
```

Every single legacy web application then initializes `HttpContext.Current.Items` in `Application_BeginRequest` based on current url (domain) and some db settings.

```
void Application_BeginRequest() 
{
  HttpContext.Current.Items["ContextID"] = QueryDb(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
}
```

My web api service will have "dynamic" context. I.E.:

```
// sample web api method
void Get() 
{
  int contextID = GetContextBasedOnHttpHeader();
  // Works but just icky
  HttpContext.Current.Items["ContextID"] = context;
  new Legacy().Foo();
}
```

Relying on http context in web api is just wrong. On the other rewriting all legacy components to inject contextID in a nice way is simply too much work.

I was thinking of abusing the `Thread.SetData` method instead - i.e.:

```
// sample web api method
void Get() 
{
  // filter would be better, but for simplicity sake
  ContextInfo.ContextID = GetContextBasedOnHttpHeader();
  new Legacy().Foo();
}
```

And rewriting the `ContextInfo` into something like this:

```
public interface IContextInfoProvider { int ContextID { get; set; } }
public class LegacyContextInfoProvider : IContextInfoProvider { ... }

public static class ContextInfo
{
  public static IContextInfoProvider Provider = new LegacyContextInfoProvider();
  public static int ContextID
  {
    return Provider.ContextID;
  }
}

public class WebApiContextInfoProvider : IContextInfoProvider
{
  public int ContextID {
    get { return (int)Thread.GetData(Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("ContextID")); }
    set { Thread.SetData(Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("ContextID"), value);
  }
}

// on startup
ContextInfo.Provider = new WebApiContextInfoProvider();
```

We can also assume that the legacy components will run in the same thread (because you can't reference `HttpContext.Current.Items` once you've fired new thread - it will be null). My concern is with the thread safety - can I use it like this without any nasty side-effect ?